# What is the maximum stack level for a C++ program?

Tags: c++, recursion, stack-overflow

I tried to see how far could I get before getting to a stack overflow by recursion in C++. I wrote this function

```
long recurse( long level ) {
    std::cout << level << std::endl;
    return recurse( ++level ) * 12 //to avoid tail recursion optimization, if present
}
```

And I called it passing 0 as the first value. The last number it printed was 349411, then it printed `Segmentation fault` and stopped running. My guess is it ran out of memory, however the same function called with the same value prints 499982 before throwing a `stack overflow` error in Lua, and I would be surprised if Lua functions had a so smaller weight on memory than C++ functions.

So what is the maximum stack level a C++ program can get to before stopping its execution?

Is it really "until it has memory", or is there a fixed limit?

Also why does it print `Segmentation fault`?

Isn't that a message only printed when memory is accessed in unauthorized ways?

Comment: That's implementation defined

Comment: This is heavily system-dependent.

Comment: What error should it print when it runs out of memory?  Maybe *Segmentation fault*?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews are you serious, or sarcastic?

Comment: @user6245072 As serious as one can be.

Comment: In Linux, OOM killer wakes up, and your process or other victim will be killed.

Comment: @akakatak You don't need to be anywhere near the OOM killer level to get a stack overflow...

Comment: @GillBates It's not even implementation-defined. The implementation is not required to document the recursion limit.

Comment: When your system's stack space runs out, you access the memory beyond it in an "unauthorized way", hence the message. Lua's call stack is managed by the Lua runtime and is completely independent.

Answer (score 5):

The amount of memory available for recursion depends on the compiler settings, operating system and the physical platform.  There is no minimum nor maximum limit.

When you run out of memory, various errors can be printed, one common message is "Segmentation fault."

> Also why does it print Segmentation fault?
>
> Isn't that a message only printed when memory is accessed in unauthorized ways?

Your program accessed memory in an unauthorized way by demanding more memory than is available or accessing memory outside your program's scope (allocation), so the operating system was nice and displayed *Segmentation fault*.  You OS could have trashed your computer or hung or rebooted.  Some platforms display a *Blue Screen Of Death*.

Comment: A reasonably modern OS will not BSoD in this situation.

Comment: @Kevin: I never considered a BSoD a reasonable action, nor that OS to be reasonable. ;-)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Windows ***95*** had basic memory protection, you know. It would BSOD, but not from a simple case of stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> I would be surprised if Lua functions had a so smaller weight on memory than C++ functions.

You're assuming that Lua is using the C++ stack for doing Lua function calls.

It isn't. Lua has its own stack for its functions, with its own limits. Just like Lua has its own memory space (admittedly provided by the host) and so forth.

The limitations of the C++ stack are implementation dependent and cannot be determined a priori.

> Isn't that a message only printed when memory is accessed in unauthorized ways?

Yes. And that's what you did. You attempted to access more stack space than you were allotted. That's accessing memory you have not been authorized to access.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is very implementation dependent. This has many factors dependent on it, mostly the available computer memory available to your compiler, which differs greatly among computers. OF course, there is no single standard for this, but the error you currently get, `Segmentation Fault`, is one of the many errors possible to be printed. Some compilers even print `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: You can have 1 TB of memory and have a compiler that restricts recursion by 1GB or the OS limits your program to only use 2GB.  Yes, there are many factors, but not necessarily the amount of memory on the platform.